# Is it possible to come over the time out issue for a function call in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, xslt

In my program I call a method

```
xslTransform.Load(strXmlQueryTransformPath, xslSettings, new XmlUrlResolver());
```

The problem I am facing is: sometimes this function doesn't execute well within the time.

Sometimes compiler raises the time out issue after a long time of trial.. which inturn causes this part of application to shut. That is what I want to avoid.

So if it exceeds certain time say 10 seconds I need to recall the method. Is it possible to add some code lines adjacent to this, which can meet the requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the method on a new `Thread`, then call `Join` on the new thread with a timeout of 10 seconds.

For example:

```
public static bool RunWithTimeout(ThreadStart method, TimeSpan timeout, int maxTries) {
    while(maxTries > 0) {
        var thread = new Thread(method);
        thread.Start();
        if (thread.Join(timeout))
            return true;
        maxTries--;
    }
    return false;
}


if (!RunWithTimeout(
    delegate { xslTransform.Load(strXmlQueryTransformPath, xslSettings, new XmlUrlResolver()); },
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
    5  //tries
))
    //Error! Waaah!
```

Comment: If timeouts occur, this code will create multiple threads, all of which will continue working until completion.  The background thread is still running if thread.Join times out.

Comment: @Paul: Yes, it will.  You could solve that by calling `Abort`, but aborts are evil.

Comment: @SLaks, I tried using this code .. sorry .. but  it is giving error ..!!

Comment: then I modified statement to "if(!RunWithTimeout(xslTransform.Load(strXmlQueryTransformPath, xslSettings, new XmlUrlResolver()), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 5)) ;" 
     now it is giving error saying "cannot convert void to System.threading.ThreadStart"

how to get out of this error??

Comment: You're running C# 2.0.  Try my edited code.  (I had been usinga C# 3 lambda expression)

Comment: no compilation error but output error is being shown up now, saying "Output-String(after transformation) is null", :(

Comment: Oops .. I was wrong, My usage of if condition was bad, I feel sorry to trouble you and disturb your valuable time ..
thanks for help and support.